# Nav sub menu not staying visible when hovered over in firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

My nav is positioned at the bottom of the page, and the sub menu appears above the nav.

I also have a bit of jquery which fades out the content when the nav is hovered on. However I think this query is interfering with the sub menu, as it doesn't stay when one hovers over it, this seems only in firefox browser?

please have a look here on a firefox browser http://intelligen.info/index.html

```
$("#nav").hover(
  function () {
    $(".index-content").fadeTo(700,0.3);
  },
  function () {
    $(".index-content").fadeTo(700,1);
  }
 );
```

Comment: For the **main** navigation items, you'll probably want to add padding, so there's a larger area to mouseover. `padding:10px 0` should do it. At the moment there's probably a slight gap between the `nav` items and the child menu, so it thinks you hovered off the main nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gap is set way to high, using bottom leaves whitespace between the hover and the element you are hovering over. Also, I wouldnt use jQuery for adding CSS elements such as fading. You can use transitions to do that.

```
#nav li:hover nav {
    bottom: 12px; /** Change to 12 to fix **/
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```